# Dynamically add field to a Django Modelform

Tags: python, django

I have read all previous posts regarding this, but none of the solutions work for me, maybe its because Django has changed something? I want to add fields dynamically to my modelform that is rendered in the django admin, in the future it will be based of fetching some information from the backend to populate the fields, but right now I just want to show a field added in the init of the model form like so:

```
class PackageFileInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = File
        exclude = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.fields += ('test2',)
        self.fields['test2'] = forms.CharField()
```

However the field test2 is not shown when rendering the form. Why?

I can also add that if I add it directly on the modelform, the field shows in the django admin:

```
class PackageFileInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    test2 = forms.CharField()
```

Here is the full code for the admin:

```
admin.site.register(Package, PackageAdmin)

class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form=PackageForm
    inlines=[PackageFileInline]

class PackageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = '__all__'

class PackageFileInline(admin.StackedInline):   
    model=File
    form=PackageFileInlineForm
    extra=0

class PackageFileInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        exclude = []

        
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.fields += ('test2',)
        self.fields['test2'] = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: How are you rendering the form?

Comment: `self._meta.fields += self._meta.fields + ('test2',)` ... you want either `self._meta.fields += ('test2',)` or `self._meta.fields = self._meta.fields + ('test2',)` here I think

Comment: @Anentropic that is absolutly true, fixed it but still not working.... Fixed it in the post as well.

Comment: You don't need to modify `_meta` to add new fields, but again: how are you rendering the form?

Comment: @AKX Ive tried both with and without the _meta... I am using django admin so I am just overwriting the form, the rendering is pure django admin.

Comment: You never mentioned you're using Django admin. Have you set e.g. `fieldsets` on the admin class?

Comment: @AKX I have added it now to the post. No I have not set anything for fieldsets on the admin class. I can add that if I add the test2 field directly on the Modelform instead of on the init it works:

class PackageFileInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    test2 = forms.CharField()

Comment: Can you please also show us the admin class where you're referring to this form class?

Comment: @AKX added it above.

Comment: @AKX Any tips on this?

Comment: @AKX only requiring more and more info, but no solutions...

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry that my volunteer help hasn't been sufficient for you.  I took some time out of my day to set up a project like yours locally and dig in a little. How dynamic do you need the fields to be? (IOW, would they change per-request, or..?) By the looks of it, you may need to override `InlineModelAdmin`'s `get_formset()`, or alternatively `get_formsets_with_inlines()` on the parent ModelAdmin, because you can't otherwise set the `fields` that `get_formset()` reads.